# Discovering Jython modules in Java .jar at runtime?

Tags: python, jython, discovery

Is there a way to discover Jython modules inside a package at runtime, if they are inside a Java .jar in the form of compiled .py$class files?

Suppose I have a module `foo` containing function `frobify`. Someone else on my team is providing a package `bar` with modules in it:

```
bar/
  __init__.py
  tweedledee.py
  tweedledum.py
  walrus.py
  carpenter.py
```

and they use Jython to compile each of these into a `.py$class` file, and then turn the `bar` directory including all `.py$class` files into `bar.jar`

Then we run Jython and execute the following:

```
import foo
import bar

foo.frobify(bar)
```

where I want to write `frobify()` to do this:

```
def frobify(package):
   for module in get_modules(package):
      do_something_with(module)
```

How could I implement `get_modules()` so that it returns a list of the modules inside the provided package? I would rather take this approach than having to force my customers to pass in a list of modules explicitly.

Comment: hmm... I just ran a Jython prompt interactively, and it looks like `dir(package)` includes the modules below it, even if you just import the package itself.

Comment: oh, crap, that only works if the package imports its submodules explicitly in  __init__.py

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Looks like [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html) can do this:

```
import sys
import pkgutil

def get_modules():
    pkg = sys.modules[__name__]
    return [importer.find_module(name).load_module(name)
                 for importer, name, ispkg 
                 in pkgutil.iter_modules(pkg.__path__)]
```

It works in Jython 2.5.3 and Python 2.7.1